# How to use login_required on Update/Create/Delete Views in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, authorization

I am trying to use `@login_reuqired` decorator. For normal functions it is working fine, but when i try to use it in my UpdateView i am getting this error `"AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'as_view'"`

This is my `view.py`

```
@login_required
class RoomUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Room
    fields = ['Name', 'RoomTypeID']
    template_name='WebApp/room_form.html'`
```

This is in my `urls.py`

```
 url(r'^roomList/updateRoom/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.RoomUpdate.as_view(), name='room_update'),
```

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 2):

For Django 1.9+ you can use a mixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class RoomUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    fields = ['Name', 'RoomTypeID']
    template_name='WebApp/room_form.html'`
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to decorate the `dispatch` method:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class RoomUpdate(UpdateView):
    model = Room
    fields = ['Name', 'RoomTypeID']
    template_name='WebApp/room_form.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required)
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(RoomUpdate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

or you can use `login_required` as a function in your `urls.py` like this:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

url(r'^roomList/updateRoom/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', login_required(views.RoomUpdate.as_view()), name='room_update'),
```

Since Django 1.9+ you also can use a mixin:

```
from django.contrib.auth.mixins import LoginRequiredMixin

class RoomUpdate(LoginRequiredMixin, UpdateView):
    fields = ['Name', 'RoomTypeID']
    template_name='WebApp/room_form.html'
```

Comment: See the docs for more details if needed: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views - or https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#the-loginrequired-mixin for the mixin, which is new to me.